pipewire microphone is detected but not working
I'm using linux-lts, kde plasma, pipewire. In settings in-build microphone is shown as active but has no sound input. My laptop is msi bravo 17 d7ve.
wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, cookie:1954505650]
 └─ Clients:
        32. kwin_wayland                        [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:869]
        33. WirePlumber                         [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:951]
        41. WirePlumber [export]                [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:951]
        48. libcanberra                         [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:1051]
        49. pipewire                            [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:1107]
        61. xdg-desktop-portal                  [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:877]
        62. kded6                               [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:1051]
        63. libcanberra                         [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:1098]
        64. plasmashell                         [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:1098]
        65.                                     [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:1098]
        66. Google Chrome input                 [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:2124]
        71. wpctl                               [1.2.3, sasha@bravo, pid:3939]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      42. HDA NVidia                          [alsa]
 │      43. Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [alsa]
 │      44. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller  [alsa]
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   56. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo [vol: 0.45]
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │      57. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo [vol: 1.00]
 │
 ├─ Filters:
 │
 └─ Streams:

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │      68. HD Webcam                           [v4l2]
 │      69. HD Webcam                           [v4l2]
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   70. HD Webcam (V4L2)
 │
 ├─ Filters:
 │
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Devices:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.usb-Sony_Interactive_Entertainment_Wireless_Stereo_Headset-00.analog-stereo
         1. Audio/Source  alsa_input.usb-Sony_Interactive_Entertainment_Wireless_Stereo_Headset-00.mono-fallback

pactl list cards
Card #42
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 57"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
        device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
        device.plugged.usec = "7907835"
        device.product.id = "0x22be"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "15"
        client.id = "41"
        object.id = "42"
        object.serial = "42"
        object.path = "alsa:acp:NVidia"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 57"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU a7 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de00a7,146213de,00100100"
        alsa.id = "NVidia"
        device.string = "0"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: off
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "3"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3

Card #43
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.1
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c8000 irq 80"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.1"
        device.description = "Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.1"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "7907761"
        device.product.id = "0x1640"
        device.product.name = "Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "15"
        client.id = "41"
        object.id = "43"
        object.serial = "43"
        object.path = "alsa:acp:Generic"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c8000 irq 80"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.mixer_name = "ATI R6xx HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100800"
        alsa.id = "Generic"
        device.string = "1"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: off
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "3"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3

Card #44
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "2"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 81"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:2"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio2"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        device.description = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "8051540"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "15"
        client.id = "41"
        object.id = "44"
        object.serial = "44"
        object.path = "alsa:acp:Generic_1"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 81"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC256"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0256,146213de,00100002"
        alsa.id = "Generic_1"
        device.string = "2"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "mic"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "speaker"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headphones"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo

arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I managed to detect my mic via hdajackretask. I rewrote pin 0x19 to internal mic in Realtek ALC256 codec. If you need more info about my system I can add it to the post asap
Whats wrong?
